# Spring : Convert Response Entity to JSON

Tags: arrays, json, spring, rest, web-services

From my rest client, i am hitting a web service and getting my response in the form of String `{"code":"00000","msg":"Success">` . Now I am converting this in the form of JSONObject which i can then use further. But i am not able to. Below is the code i am using . Please guide.

```
private ResponseEntity<String> test()
{
    final String uri = "URL";

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);       
    ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);       
    System.out.println(result);

    //This part is not working.
    try {
        JSONObject arr = new JSONObject((result));
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject abc = arr.getJSONObject(i);
          System.out.println("test1 : " + abc.getString("test1"));
          System.out.println("test2 : " + abc.getString("test2"));
          System.out.println("test3 : " + abc.getString("test3"));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of converting to a generic JSONObject, you should create a class matching your response.
Spring will map the response to your model class using Jackson(behind the scenes).  There is no need for converting it yourself.

So Let's say, you create a class

```
class Response {
String code;
String message:

//Gettes and Setters
}
```

Now you can change your code a bit like this

```
 ResponseEntity<Response> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Response.class);
```

Now if you use`result.getBody()`, this would give your Response object, which you can use

Comment: this makes me so mad.  GetforObject can unmarshal to an object automatically.  Am I in the boat that I have to parse that with jackson now by hand?

Answer (score -4):

One form is using JSONObject

```html
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
   <scope>${scope}</scope>
  </dependency>
```

```html
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
  
json.put("key1", value1);
json.put("key2", value2);
```

Comment: But how do i convert responseentity to json?